# Como cargar index desde localhost con Node

Tags: html, nodejs, css3, express, localhost

Mi problema  es que no se como cargar las vistas en un proyecto, estaba trabajando con express y postman pero por consola todo y ahora quiero agregarle un index pero al llamar al localhost:4000 me trae solo el HTML sin CSS, ya he intentado con ruta completa y alternativa incluso con algo de asset que vi ahi pero nada, incluso cambie los estilos a una carpeta public y asset pero tampoco,
como hago para que al llamar al localhost me traiga mi pagina principal?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(assets/css/style.css) }}" type="text/css">
```

Comment: ¿Qué motor de renderizado utilizas? Tal como se ve tu código, no parece que uses ninguno desde el lado servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que servir todos los ficheros como estáticos para que funcione de la manera que lo estas planteando.

```js
//Install express server
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'))

app.get('/', (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/index.html'))
)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
```